# Showing $R^n\setminus \{0\}$ are connected

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, proof-explanation

The following example is from my book of Topology of Metric Spaces:

> Definitions: $S^n = \{x\in R^{n+1}:\langle x,x\rangle = 1 \}$
>
> Example: When $n>1$, $R^n\smallsetminus \{0\}$ are connected. In fact, the function $h:S^n\times(0,+\infty)\to R^n\smallsetminus\{0\}$ given by $h(x,t) = t\cdot x$ is a homeomorphism, whose inverse is $k:R^n\smallsetminus\{0\}\to S^n\times(0,+\infty)$, $k(z) = (z/|z|, |z|)$.

The functions $h$ and $k$ doesn't seem well defined for me, because for $h$, $h(x,t)$ should be in $R^n$, but $t\cdot x$ is in $R^{n+1}$ (as the definition of $S^n$ states), similarly for $k$ (in the other direction).

Despite this fact, I'm ok with these being continuous and with $R^n\smallsetminus \{0\}$ being connected because it is homeomorph to a cartesian product of connected sets (which is connected).

Any help to clarify this will be appreciated.

Comment: Yes, I believe the intent is for $h$ to be a function into $\mathbb{R}^{n+1} \setminus \{0\}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you are right, there is a typo. The functions, as written, are homeomorphisms of $S^n \times (0,\infty)$ and $\mathbb R^{n+1} \setminus \{0\}$, not $\mathbb R^n \setminus \{0\}$. In particular you could conclude from the connectedness of both $S^n$ and $(0,\infty)$ that $\mathbb R^{n+1}\setminus \{0\}$ is connected, but note that proving that $S^n$ is connected is probably slightly harder than proving that $\mathbb R^{n+1} \setminus \{0\}$ is connected, and certainly not easier.